# almasaeed2010/adminlte v2.4.18 requires bower-asset/jquery

Tags: jquery, bower, adminlte

I am attempting to install almasaeed2010/adminlte v2.4.18 via composer, however, I am getting the following error

```
almasaeed2010/adminlte v2.4.18 requires bower-asset/jquery >=1.9.0 <4.0.0 -> no matching package found.
```

I can not seem to find bower-asset/jquery in packagist, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the asset-packagist repository, you can follow the instructions on

```
 https://asset-packagist.org/
```

and then I added

```
 "bower-asset/jquery": "^2.2"
```

to the require section